# Magento - Product image spacing at top and bottom

Tags: php, image, magento

For some reason when uploading a product image, magento is adding some spacing to the top and bottom of the image.

This is an example image. Because Stackoverflow has a white background, if you save this image you will see the white spacing along the top and bottom.

[image: This is an example image. If you save this image you will see the white spacing along the top and bottom.]

[This is a link to the site if you'd like to have a look in the store environment.](http://blracing.co.uk/bearings/ceramic-agama-clutch-bearings-1pair.html)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by your theme's aspect ratio set on the thumbnail images.  Since the image size is set to `232 x 280`, and the image you are uploading is square, Magneto automatically generates a version of the image at the size it's called.

To modify the size and set it to a square aspect ratio, you can simply modify your theme's template file.

Open `app/design/frontend/default/celebrity/templates/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Look for your image tag(s), it will look something like this:

`<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(232,280); ?>" width="232" height="280" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />`

Modify the height and width values to be the same, like this:

`<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(232); ?>" width="232" height="232" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />`

Save the file, and refresh your Magento caches.